# why do my constraints make the layout different while running app on iphone 5 and iphone 6?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint, layoutsubviews

I am designing a `swift` app that shows a photo, map and content - all of that in `UITableView` header.

When I run the app on iphone 5, it looks like this:

[image]

The yellow field is a text view that has the following constraints:

[image]

and:

[image]

This looks fine on iphone 5. However, when I run it on iphone 6, I see:

[image]

I don't understand why those two views differ.

Now, in my code, in `viewDidLoad()` I have a call for method:

```
defineHeaderView()
```

that basically populates the header view with data (e.g. fills the username, text, photo).

I also have this block of code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    sizeHeaderToFit()
}

func sizeHeaderToFit() {
    let headerView = myTable.tableHeaderView!

    headerView.setNeedsLayout()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var frame = headerView.frame
    frame.size.height = height
    headerView.frame = frame

    myTable.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

In the `storyboard` I define the headerview as a view inside the `UITableView`:

[image]

Can you explain me why does the view differ on both screens?

To give a better insight, here are the other constraints:

Map:

[image]

and the background photo that is here:

[image]

has the following constraints:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is with your imageViews. The iPhone 5 screen is slimmer, and depending on how your images and constraints are sized, (and if clipSubviews is set to true/false) the images will look very different.

Comment: You should try debugging the view hierarchy on the different devices to check what the actual frames/constraints are

Comment: There is not enough information about names of your views and other constraints. So this is just an assumption:
Constraint for your views height (the yellow one) is related by "greater or equal". According to your second constraint, the top side of your view should be 644 point below parents top - it's a static value. So on devices with different sizes (heights) your view will be stretched in height.

Comment: Guys, I added more details about my constraints, hopefully it will help you with understanding my problem

Comment: The top of your text field is constrained to the top of e view. It should be constrained to the bottom of the map view.

Comment: @Paulw11 as you suggested, I tried that, but there's one thing that does not work well... When the text is long enough, at some point the `UILabel` stops growing and instead of full text it shows three dots at the end --> http://imgur.com/a/QMSKf This problem occurs only when I remove the constraint from the top of view and instead of that put the constraint to the map... I have no idea why it happens though

Comment: @Paulw11 also, despite having constraint `textView height >= 95`, when the text is short, the textview is losing its proper height and adjust to the text, like this: http://imgur.com/a/LbFP5

Comment: make sure the `lines` property of your text field is set to 0. You may also need to reduce the vertical content hugging value for your text field

Comment: @Paulw11 the `lines` property is equal to 0, and speaking about the vertical content hugging - currently I have those values: http://imgur.com/a/GmQld can you give me a hint which field and for what value should I change it?

Comment: Decrease the vertical to 250

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the hint, it didn't help though, the label - with a very short text - is still small, definitely not `95` in height :(

Comment: @EugeneSvaro I have a constraint `greater or equal` because first - there can be a very long text, and second - because - as visible on the very first screen - I have an upvote and downvote button there and I want to show them in a correct position - for that I need to have at least 95 in height

Comment: @user3766930 Ok, i've read some new comments. Then you can use Paulw11 approach, but with some modifications:
1. You can try to use dynamic table view cell height by adding in your tableview configurations lines:
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
2. You can override override: func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat
and calculate your tableviewcell height by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the top constraint of your UILabel.

Comment: When I remove the top constraint then my `UILabel` goes to the very top of the screen...

Comment: I don't know if this is an effective answer, but it would be a *better* answer if you add an explanation of *why* this will fix the issue.

Comment: I just added more information about the constraints to the original question

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your desire screen? Based on that I will suggest you the constraint setup

Comment: @KuntalGajjar my desired screen is the first one in my question, as seen on iphone 5, I want to have the description below the map also on iphone 6, and currently it overlaps